# Unable to increase MySql open-files-limit

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have modified `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` as follows

```
[mysqld]
open-files-limit = 100000
[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit = 100000
```

Still when login to mysql I am not seeing any change in this variable

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| open_files_limit | 1024  |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have first tried using open_files_limit but read somewhere that we need to replace underscore(_) with dash(-) in this variable

I am using **`ubuntu 15.10`**
Any help?

---

I have tried following things too

```
http://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit
http://serverfault.com/questions/440878/changing-open-files-limit-in-mysql-5-5
```

-------Also made change to following file

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
open-files-limit    = 15000
#
```

Comment: did you restart mysql process?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted MYSQL after every change.

Comment: Let me guess, you used `innodb_file_per_table = 1` and now you are trying to fix the limit of files MySQL can have open?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are installing Mysql through synaptic manager then on latest ubuntu version 15.10 increasing open_file_limit from my.cnf file will not work. You need to do following changes.

```
1. Open /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service as super user
2. Add the following lines to the end of it:

LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity

3. Execute sudo systemctl daemon-reload

4. Restart mysql.
```

Comment: You must also restart mysql using `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` and `/etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: This makes no sense. If I can't raise limits defined in ulimit -a 
Then when mysql reach the threshold defined there something will happen badly.

Comment: Other solutions set actual numbers for `LimitNOFILE`, which can't be right. Using `infinity` could be right if you set the real values in mysql config files.